# ls -a command is not working on my VS Code terminal

Tags: powershell

```
ls : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\LENOVO\learngit\~a' because it does not exist.
+ ls ~a
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\LENOVO\learngit\~a:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
 
PS C:\Users\LENOVO\learngit> ls -a
Get-ChildItem : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'a' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Attributes -Directory -File 
-Hidden -ReadOnly -System.
+ ls -a
+    ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: Hi could tell us more. I do not understand what are you doing. What operating system  do you use?

Comment: It looks like a wrong `ls` is invoked. Looking at the style of error messages, I'm sure that it's a version of `ls` from Powershell. Likely you expected to invoke `ls` from Git Bash. Probably you need to adjust `%PATH%` settings, or simply learn how to use Powershell `ls`.

Comment: how to adjust %path% setting please tell

Comment: `ls` is not a Git command; this has nothing to do with Git at all. I switched the tag to powershell but that might be just as wrong. It's probably at least *closer*, so that someone can provide the correct tag, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` in PowerShell is an alias to [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1). That's why you see the  below error

> Get-ChildItem : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'a' is ambiguous

The `-a` option is in [Linux `ls`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) which has nothing to do with PowerShell's `ls`. To list all files with `Get-ChildItem` you use `-Force`

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Force
ls -Fo
```

If you want to use the Linux `ls` command then you need to run it in a Unix shell like bash. If you have git on Windows then bash and other GNU tools should already be there for use

If GNU tools is available then of course you can also run GNU `ls` from PowerShell, but you must explicitly specify the `.exe` extension or remove the `ls` alias, but none of these are recommended

```powershell
ls.exe
Remove-Alias ls # Don't do this
ls -a
```